# Adding BackTrace to the Hoptoad Notify method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hoptoad

I have the code as shown below:

```
 raise "Invalid destination "
rescue Exception => e
        HoptoadNotifier.notify(:error_class => e, :error_message => "#{e} : Error occured for the user #{self.user_name}")
```

I actually want the error message to be logged in the hoptoad as `"Invalid destination : Error occured for the user username"`. The code as shown above works as intented. But im not able to get the back trace in the hoptoad. Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly pass `e.backtrace` to `Hoptoad.nofity`:

```
raise "Invalid destination "
rescue Exception => e
  HoptoadNotifier.notify(:error_class => e, :error_message => "#{e} : Error occured for the user #{self.user_name}", :parameters => { backtrace => e.backtrace })
```